# Playing video frame-by-frame very slow on Chrome/Firefox but not on Safari

Tags: javascript, video, browser

I have a use case that consists in seeking specific frames in a video. The frequency of frame changes can be quite high as it depends on mouse movements. My problem is that depending on the browser the updates can be very smooth (Safari) or introduce a lot of latency (Chrome/Firefox).

I came up with an example to test the differences between browsers using the following code (here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/brufru/pen/NWyJbpz)). I am using this [video](https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/360/Big_Buck_Bunny_360_10s_1MB.mp4) that is 10 seconds long and 60fps and I play it frame-by-frame by changing its currentTime at an interval equals to the video's frame rate.

**HTML**

```
<video id="player" src="https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/360/Big_Buck_Bunny_360_10s_1MB.mp4" preload="auto"/>
```

**JS**

```
window.onload = () => {
  const player = document.getElementById("player")
  setInterval(() => {
    player.currentTime = (player.currentTime + 0.016) % 10
  }, 16)
}
```

The main problem seems to me that Chrome and Firefox just handle video time changes differently than Safari, and my use case is well supported in the latter. Would there be any way to also make that work smoothly in Chrome/Firefox? I checked a few video player libraries (e.g., plyr, react-player, video-js) but they are all based on native HTML5 players.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having similar issues, I found out the problem has to do with the video encoding. The significant parameter is the **keyframe interval** that, if I got it correctly, defines the size of the chunk of frames a specific frame would refer to when rendering. The smaller this number, the faster the response when rendering it, but I guess the files can grow bigger as less information is compressed.

You can modify this parameter using the `-g` and `-min_keyint` options with ffmpeg https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html.